# Deleted folder/files in window server 2012 r2 keep reappearing after sometime?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

- I had checked on the permission setting, seem like not the one causing this issue as the user are allowed to delete.
- I had also tried to delete from local, from the server itself, but the folder still appearing after sometime, normally 1 day later.
- Some files inside another folder face the same issue, as after delete it will reappear after sometime.
- As some of the files inside both of the folder have same name, because the 2nd folder was the duplicate of the 1st folder, so some of the files in 2nd was copied from 1st one, and now the user wan to delete the 1st one but could not.
- I had also tried to rename the 1st folder n delete, but it still reappear back.

Could someone help me on this? I really couldn't think what was the cause of this.

Comment: No one encounter same problem before? would it be related with the file server configuration?

Comment: no one can help me on this?

Comment: Does your environment use DFS?